# Animate top position based on scroll when element is in view

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

I have a div that is absolutely positioned so its top is touching its parents. Here is an example of it (the black box) https://imgur.com/a/d7LbP. I am trying to have it so that when it is in view (when you can see it on the viewport) it scrolls down to the bottom of its parent based on how much a user scrolls. (Like a parallax background)

I currently have the code working to check when the element is in view, but needs some help getting the parallax like function working. Here is what I have so far

```
    $('article.featured').each(function(){
        var $bgobj = $(this).children('.the-content'); // assigning the object
        var $speed = 5; // setting the speed
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var yPos = ($window.scrollTop() / $speed);
            // Put together our final background position
            var coords = yPos + 'px';
            // Move the background
            $bgobj.css({ top: coords });
        });
    });
```

This is working but it is basing the position of the box based on the offset of the view port rather then the amount of scrolling when the element comes into view.

Any comments pointing me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

Here is what the html for it looks like

```
    <article class="featured cf check-view">
    <div class="featured-img" data-type="background" data-speed="5" style="background-image:url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150');">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="the-content">
        <h3><img class="logo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt=""></h3>
        <p class="tags">Web Development / WordPress</p>
        <p>Interactive responsive WordPress site.</p>
        <a href="">View Project</a>
    </div>
</article>
```

Here is a link to the working example if you need to see what I'm trying to achieve. http://staging.alexkinejara.com

Comment: When is it not in view? And when it isn't in view, what is it's positioning?

Comment: @AaronEveleth it is absolutely positioned to the top of its parent. What I mean by 'in view' is when it is visible to the user on the viewport. When the site loads you have to scroll a bit before you get to this section.

Comment: Oh ok, I assumed that was a navbar, my bad. So let me understand what you are trying to accomplish. You have `element a` and it's parent `element b`. `element a` by default sits at the top of `element b`. When `element a` comes into view, you want it to start moving down towards the bottom of `element b`, ultimately stopping at the bottom of `element b` once `element a` is going out of view. Is this correct?

Comment: @AaronEveleth yea that's exactly what I am trying to achieve! Well actually its not sitting 'at the top' the top of element a its touching the top of element b. Sorry if my explanation was confusing.

Comment: No worries, just wanted to make sure I understood correctly. I'll work on adding an answer here in a bit. Also, could you edit your post and add your html? It would help a lot.

Comment: @AaronEveleth thanks! Here is a link to a working example if you want to take a look at it http://staging.alexkinejara.com/